# Parse table from Wikipedia

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-agility-pack

I need to read the whole table at this web page https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episodi_di_Watchmen

I don't care about header, but of course I need to read each rows and columns. I wrote this code:

```
string page = "https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episodi_di_Watchmen";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(page).GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);

doc.Load(reader);
List<List<string>> table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='wikitable']")
                        .Descendants("tr").Select(x => x.ChildNodes.Select(c => c.InnerText.Trim())
                        .Where(y => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y)).ToList()).ToList();
```

Unfortunately the code above gives an error on the List-line. Making some trials, it seem like the error is in the Descendants method.

Can you help me?

Comment: You should be using the [Wikimedia API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) and not trying to scrape the Wikipedia page.

Comment: I start thinking I MUST use Wikimedia API, because my code was working untill few days ago. I need to study it, I have never worked with something like that,

Answer (score 0):

The `HtmlDocument.Load(TextReader reader)` failed to create the `DocumentNode`: it was `null`. Maybe because the `TextReader` does not have the `public` assignable Encoding field. This is why you got the exception.
Here is the working code:

```
class WikiTable
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<List<string>>> LoadWikiTable(string requestUriString)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(WebRequest
                                                        .Create(requestUriString)
                                                        .GetResponse()
                                                        .GetResponseStream(),
                                                      Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            await Task.Run(() => 
                           doc.Load(reader.BaseStream /*, Encoding.UTF8*/));
        }

        return doc.DocumentNode
                  .SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='wikitable']")
                  .Descendants("tr")
                  .Select(x => x.ChildNodes
                              .Select(c => c.InnerText.Trim())
                              .Where(y => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y))
                              .ToList()
                          );
    }

    public static string Table2String(IEnumerable<List<string>> table)
    {
        string Row2String(List<string> row) => string.Join("\t", row);

        return string.Join("\n", 
                           table.Select(row => Row2String(row)));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var table = new WikiTable().LoadWikiTable2("https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episodi_di_Watchmen");
Console.WriteLine(WikiTable.Table2String(table.Result));
```

What do you think?

Comment: It doesn't work. table.Result is null. I think Wikipedia changed something because untill few days ago there were no problem with that.